# Link weather data connection between Fragment and Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, weather

I'm building a weather app using https://openweathermap.org/current and so far, everything has been going smoothly. The activity part of the app uses city query from my interface to give the current data of any city searched on the edittext. The issue now is that I'm using only a search button(on my activity), but I want to as well receive the same data in the fragment class. For example, I'm using activity for:
1.Searching and displaying the city name. 2. Displaying the current time of those cities.

And fragment for getting the temp, sunrise & sunset, humidity, and other data for the cities searched on the activity.

So I can't implement a double search button(in activity and fragment) just to get the data. I aim to use just the activity own to get the city data in both classes because my fragment class as well contains textviews for receiving data, I'll appreciate any way to achieve this because I have no idea how to do this myself.

I have tried calling the same method on the fragment class but I get compile error from this code in the Fragment:

```
private void getWeatherData(String name) {

            ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

            Call<Example> call = apiInterface.getWeatherData(name);
```

Saying: `'getWeatherData' is never used` and `cannot resolve symbol 'name'` (Because my search button and edittext is used in activity alone)

I don't get a single error in Activity

This is my full code:

**HomeActivity.java**

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // User current time
    TextView time_field;
    ImageView Search;
    EditText textfield;
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    public static int count=0;
    int[] drawable =new int[]{R.drawable.dubai,R.drawable.central_bank_of_nigeria,R.drawable.eiffel_tower,R.drawable.hong_kong,R.drawable.statue_of_liberty};
    Timer _t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        time_field = findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        Search = findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        textfield = findViewById(R.id.textfield);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);

        Search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                getWeatherData(textfield.getText().toString().trim());


                            constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
                            constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dubai);
                            _t = new Timer();
                            _t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // run on ui thread
                                    runOnUiThread(() -> {
                                        if (count < drawable.length) {

                                            constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(drawable[count]);
                                            count = (count + 1) % drawable.length;
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }, 5000, 5000);
                        }

            private void getWeatherData(String name) {

                ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

                Call<Example> call = apiInterface.getWeatherData(name);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<Example> call, @NotNull Response<Example> response) {

                        assert response.body() != null;
                        time_field.setText(String.valueOf(response.body().getDt()));



                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<Example> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }


                });
            }




        });
    }
}
```

**FirstFragment.java**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    // User current time, current temperature, current condition, sunrise, sunset, temperature, pressure, humidity, wind_speed, visibility, clouds
    TextView current_temp, current_output, rise_time, set_time, temp_out, Press_out, Humid_out, Ws_out, Visi_out, Cloud_out;
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment SecondFragment.
     */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FirstFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        current_temp = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        current_output = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        rise_time = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView25);
        set_time = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView26);
        temp_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView28);
        Press_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView29);
        Humid_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView30);
        Ws_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView33);
        Visi_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView34);
        Cloud_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView35);

        private void getWeatherData(String name) {

            ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

            Call<Example> call = apiInterface.getWeatherData(name);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<Example> call, @NotNull Response<Example> response) {
                    current_temp.setText(response.body().getMain().getTemp() + " ℃");
                    current_output.setText(response.body().getWeatherList().get(0).getDescription());
                    rise_time.setText(response.body().getSys().getSunrise() + " ");
                    set_time.setText(response.body().getSys().getSunset() + " ");
                    temp_out.setText(response.body().getMain().getTemp() + " ℃");
                    Press_out.setText(response.body().getMain().getPressure() + " hpa");
                    Humid_out.setText(response.body().getMain().getHumidity() + " %");
                    Ws_out.setText(response.body().getWind().getSpeed() + " Km/h");
                    Visi_out.setText(response.body().getVisibility() + " m");
                    Cloud_out.setText(response.body().getClouds().getAll()+ " %");
        }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<Example> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
    }
            return rootView;
    }
}
```

**ApiInterface:**

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("weather?&appid=(My app key)&units=metric")
    Call<Example> getWeatherData(@Query("q") String name);
}
```

**ApiClient:**

```
public class ApiClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static  Retrofit getClient(){ //creating object

        if (retrofit == null) {

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }

        return retrofit;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using java methods unlike its syntax:

You don't get any error in your activity because you've defined it inside of an anonymous class, but you get an error in your fragment because you've written it inside of another method which is not ok in java.

So, write your method out of another (outside of the onCreateView) and then call it there.

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    // User current time, current temperature, current condition, sunrise, sunset, temperature, pressure, humidity, wind_speed, visibility, clouds
    TextView current_temp, current_output, rise_time, set_time, temp_out, Press_out, Humid_out, Ws_out, Visi_out, Cloud_out;
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment SecondFragment.
     */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FirstFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        current_temp = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        current_output = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        rise_time = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView25);
        set_time = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView26);
        temp_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView28);
        Press_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView29);
        Humid_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView30);
        Ws_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView33);
        Visi_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView34);
        Cloud_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView35);
        getWeatherData("Blah blah blah");
        return rootView;
    }

    private void getWeatherData(String name) {

        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<Example> call = apiInterface.getWeatherData(name);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<Example> call, @NotNull Response<Example> response) {
                current_temp.setText(response.body().getMain().getTemp() + " ℃");
                current_output.setText(response.body().getWeatherList().get(0).getDescription());
                rise_time.setText(response.body().getSys().getSunrise() + " ");
                set_time.setText(response.body().getSys().getSunset() + " ");
                temp_out.setText(response.body().getMain().getTemp() + " ℃");
                Press_out.setText(response.body().getMain().getPressure() + " hpa");
                Humid_out.setText(response.body().getMain().getHumidity() + " %");
                Ws_out.setText(response.body().getWind().getSpeed() + " Km/h");
                Visi_out.setText(response.body().getVisibility() + " m");
                Cloud_out.setText(response.body().getClouds().getAll()+ " %");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<Example> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Plus, if you want to access your activity widget from your fragment, you can use:

```
editText editText = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textfield);
editText.getText().toString()
```

Comment: This didn't work. The errors even got bigger. If your really sure about how to do it, I'd like you to show me in full detail the step-by-step procedure to take. Outside of oncreate is unspecific.

Comment: When you moved your method outside of your onCreateView in you fragment, what kind of error you got?

Comment: All my textviews went red, the layout inflater became invalid

Comment: At least you must not get that error if you have moved properly, see my edit and notice the next issues if you get

Comment: The setup is fine when I tested, but that "Blah blah blah" part you wrote, I replace it with textfield.getText().toString().trim() to get data using my edittext search. The problem now is that the edittext view is located in the activity, not the fragment. So I get cannot resolve symbol textfield as error now.

Comment: I have explained how to access your activity widget through your fragment, so you may not have any problem anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229017/discussion-between-chinez-and-amk).